# how can I superimpose one image over another using bootstrap 2.0?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get text and image overlay using bootstrap 2.0. I'm getting crazy. How can I get it? Thanks for help.

[Example](http://i1348.photobucket.com/albums/p740/jarab82/disen3030o_zpsc9f52cd6.png)

HTML

```
           <div class="row">
                <img id='bgtittle' src='img/header.jpg' />
                <div class="span8">
                    <img id='iphone' src='img/iphone.png' />
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <h4>EVERMIC APP</h4>
                    <p>Aplicacion oficial para mostrar nuestros trabajos</p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
                            Contacta con nosotros
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```css
 #bgtittle{
         position: relative;
         z-index: 1;
 }
 #iphone{
         position: relative;
         z-index: 2;
 }
```

Comment: Please explain what you want in more detail.

Comment: I'm trying to upload an image that clearly explains what I want to do, but I can't privileges

Comment: @Evan I added a link where you can look a picture that I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to change the position type to absolute. But then you have other problems like scrolling. For example:

```
#bgtittle{
     position: absolute;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: did you change the css for #iphone also? check http://jsfiddle.net/FjAYQ/1/ but you can see the problem with the text on the page.